# conditional expected value of order statistics

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Let $_{(1)}$,...,$_{()}$ be the order statistics of a set of $$ independent uniform $(0,1)$ random variables. I need to calculate
$$E[(X_{(2)}-(X_{(1)}+a))^{+} | X_{(1)}<a],$$
where $Y^{+}$ is is positive part of $Y.$

It is known that $X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}$
has the $Beta(1,n-1+1)$ distribution.

Hence
$$E[(X_{(2)}-(X_{(1)}+a))^{+} | X_{(1)}<a]=\frac{E[(X_{(2)}-(X_{(1)}+a))^{+} I_{X_{(1)}<a}]}{P(X_{(1)}<a)}\le \frac{E[(X_{(2)}-(X_{(1)}+a))^{+}]}{P(X_{(1)}<a)},$$
where $I$ is a indicator function.
Is it inequality
$$E[(X_{(2)}-(X_{(1)}+a))^{+} I_{X_{(1)}<a}]\le E[(X_{(2)}-(X_{(1)}+a))^{+}]=E[(X_{(1)}-a))^{+}]$$
correct?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I think your expectation can be calculated in closed form, although it is tedious to do so.

The key is to first obtain the joint distribution of the first two order statistics $(X_{(1)}, X_{(2)})$.  This is easy enough, and [Wikipedia provides the necessary formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution):

$$f_{X_{1}, X_{2}}(x,y) = n(n-1) (1-y)^{n-2}, \quad 0 \le x \le y \le 1.$$

Then the desired expectation, for $0 < a < 1$ and $n \ge 2$, is

$$\begin{align}
E(a) &= \operatorname{E}[(X_{(2)} - (X_{(1)} + a))^+ \mid X_{(1)} \le a] \\
&= \frac{\int_{x=0}^a \int_{y=x}^1 \max(0, y - x - a) f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}} (x, y) \, dy \, dx }{\int_{x=0}^a \int_{y=x}^1 f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}} (x,y) \, dy \, dx} \\
&= \frac{\int_{x=0}^{\min(a,1-a)} \int_{y=x+a}^1 (y-x-a) (1-y)^{n-2} \, dy \, dx}{\int_{x=0}^a \int_{y=x}^1 (1-y)^{n-2}  \, dy \, dx}.
\end{align}$$

Notice the condition $0 \le x \le \min(a,1-a)$.  This occurs because we simultaneously require $0 \le x \le a$ and $x+a \le y \le 1$, the latter of which implies $x \le 1 - a$.

We now proceed to evaluate the numerator and denominator separately.  The denominator is

$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^a \int_{y=x}^1 (1-y)^{n-2}  \, dy \, dx
= \int_{x=0}^a \frac{(1-x)^{n-1}}{n-1} \, dx 
= \frac{1 - (1-a)^n}{n(n-1)}.
\end{align}$$

The numerator is
$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^{\min(a, 1-a)} \int_{y=x+a}^1 (y-x-a) (1-y)^{n-2} \, dy \, dx
&= \int_{x=0}^{\min(a, 1-a)} \int_{u=0}^{1-(x+a)} u^{n-2} (1-x-a-u) \, du \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^{\min(a, 1-a)} \left[(1-x-a)\frac{u^{n-1}}{n-1} - \frac{u^n}{n} \right]_{u=0}^{1-x-a} \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^{\min(a, 1-a)} \frac{(1-x-a)^n}{n(n-1)} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{n(n-1)} \int_{v=\max(0,1-2a)}^{1-a} v^n \, dv \\
&= \frac{(1-a)^{n+1} - \max(0,(1-2a))^{n+1}}{(n+1)n(n-1)}.
\end{align}$$

Putting this together,

$$\begin{align}
E(a) &= \frac{(1-a)^{n+1} - \max(0, (1-2a))^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1 - (1-a)^n)} \\
&= \begin{cases} 
\frac{(1-a)^n - (1-2a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1-(1-a)^n)}, & 0 < a \le 1/2 \\ 
\frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1-(1-a)^n)}, & 1/2 < a < 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Simulation corroborates this result; e.g., for $n = 5$, $a = 1/7$, the expectation is $\frac{403}{4926}$, and with the *Mathematica* code

```
Max[0, (#[[2]] - #[[1]] - 1/7)] & /@ 
     Select[ParallelTable[Take[Sort[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5]], 2], {10^7}],
     First[#] <= 1/7 &]
```

I obtained a sample mean on $10^7$ simulations of approximately $0.0817691$.